# Property does not seem to be used?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is something that I came across in the Apple reference material - [Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/avTouch/Listings/Classes_avTouchController_mm.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008636-Classes_avTouchController_mm-DontLinkElementID_16) when researching how to use NSTimer, I am not asking about NSTimer as thats a [seperate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945028/repeating-nstimer-weak-reference-owning-reference-or-ivar) but I am curious about the use of the @property, the direct assignment to the iVar (i.e. not using the property setter) and the subsequent release.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *updateTimer;
...
@synthesize updateTimer;
...
updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(updateCurrentTime) userInfo:p repeats:YES];
...
...
updateTimer = nil;
...
...
// Dealloc method
[updateTimer release];
```

My question is, does the property get used at all, it seems not? Also the release, does that work, where is the retain if the @property setter is not being used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The retain is in the definition of the property.  (i.e. where it says "(nonatomic, retain)" in brackets.)

**If** the property had been allocated, it would be retained "automatically" by the setter it at that time.

***But just as you say*** the property itself is never used, so it is never allocated or retained.

The release you can see in the code appears to be **simply wrong**, just as you say. The ivar was never retained so a release would crash **just as Bjorn pointed out**.

(Note that they apparently set it to nil -- of course you can send any message at all to nil, but just as you say it's a really silly example. You can't release something you never retained.)

Exactly as you say, the example is a little weird. There was "no reason" to make a property: just as you say it was never used.  Conversely, why did they release the ivar - which was never retained.

So in short **your suspicions seem to be correct**!

There are at least three horrible errors in that code!

Comment: So, if dealloc was called (I know its not called when an app quits now) the release would cause an error? Just not sure what happens if you release an unassigned property.

Comment: Much appreciated Joe, I was just doing a little of my own research with regards to the "Other" NSTimer question and thought that checking the Apple examples might be a good idea. Little did I realise that it would add more confusion, thank you for verifying what I was thinking.

Comment: It's ok to send messages to nil in Obj-c so you wouldn't get an error

Comment: In the case above the release in dealloc is completely unnecessary as you never allocated an instance of NSTimer nor accessed it via it's synthesised getter.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the property is never used as there is no call like `self.updateTimer = something` or `[self setUpdateTimer:something]`. Sending the `release` message in `-dealloc` "works" because you reset `updateTimer` to `nil`. It is perfectly fine to send messages to `nil`, but nothing is going to happen. If you did not reset the variable to `nil`, the message would have been sent to a deallocated instance and cause an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception.

Comment: Yes, if it is autoreleased (which the timer is in this case), never retained and the variable pointing to that object is not set to nil it will crash if you send it a release message.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a dot, the property method gets called. Otherwise it is simple assignment. For instance, `foo = bar` would be assignment, whereas `self.foo = bar` would result in the property method getting called.

Try using `self.updateTimer = ...`.