# NSTimer bad access

Tags: crash, nstimer, retain

I'm trying to create an NSTimer, then invalidate and release it, then set it to a new timer. However, I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to set the timer member var again.

Code below:

1) I set the timer member var (it's set to retain)

```
self.mPageTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kPageTimerInterval target:self selector:@selector(pageTimerCallback) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

2) I let it go

```
    [mPageTimer invalidate];
    [mPageTimer release];
```

This results in the crash when I try to call the snippet in step 1 again, but I am not sure why. I retained it by setting it, and then I release it, so shouldn't the object be taken care of and my member var ok to set to a new allocated timer?

If I do this, it doesn't crash and works fine:

```
    [mPageTimer invalidate];
    [mPageTimer release];
    mPageTimer = nil;
```

I can't see how I'm doing something wrong with releasing the object, because, regardless of if that were the case, shouldn't I be able to always set my member var to whatever newly created nstimer, leak or not?

Comment: Check anywhere else in you code, you are passing messages to `mPageTimer` after its `release`. Because you can pass messages to `nil` its is not probably crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it safe to assume, that...

1. snippet 2) is *not* from the setter of the `@property`, but from another method **while** you
2. simply `@synthesize mPageTimer` **and**
3. the declaration for the timer is `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer* mPageTimer`?
   (whether nonatomic or atomic doesn't matter)

**If that's the case**, your crash is expected:

```
create timer (timer retains you, timer is autoreleased!)
schedule timer (runloop retains the timer)
assignment through setter (you retain the timer)
... (time passes)
has it fired?
Yes:
    since your timer is non-recurring, the runloop has marked it
    as invalid and released it after invocation of "pageTimerCallback:"
calling "invalidate":
    has it fired?
    No:
        runloop unschedules and releases
    Yes:
        noop or release (read: "I don't know and admittedly don't care")
calling "release" (you are no longer the owner)
... (time passes)
assignment through synthesized setter:
    [newTimer retain];
    [oldTimer release]; // Crash due to overrelease!
```

So in short:
**If** you have a property for a timer, **provide your own setter and make every access use it**.
(Two exceptions allowed: 1. implementation of the setter 2. in dealloc where you `release` the timer*)

(* Don't invalidate a timer that you're the target of in dealloc: [It is *absolutely* pointless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945028/repeating-nstimer-weak-reference-owning-reference-or-ivar/4946038#4946038)!)

Comment: You're correct on your 3 assumptions above. From reading your post and your link, can I gather that, because the runloop retains my timer, that instead of writing a setter, I could declare it as assign and not retain and then use calls to invalidate as a means of interrupting/shutting-down a timer before it fires? This would mean I'd create it with scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval and not need to call release, right?

Comment: There needs to be an English translation for the German word "Jein"! Yes, it's not necessary to retain the timer, because the runloop already does. No, _if_ you decide to store the timer through a `@property`, I urge you to provide your own setter (regardless of whether the property is assigned or retained). That said: If you _really_ need to keep a reference to the timer in order to cancel it, make sure that after the implementation of `pageTimerCallback` returned, your reference to the timer is `nil`.